# Eclipse Oxygen.3a renaming refactoring

Tags: maven, eclipse-oxygen

I started with a new maven multi module project in eclipse
with the following modules:

```
<modules>
   <module>api</module>
   <module>client</module>
   <module>server</module>
</modules>
```

Whenever I rename a method/class in the api projects,
which is a dependency of client and server module the
method/class is not renamend in the client and server 
Java files.

Even if I rename a method call from api in the client/server 
modules, the method in api is renamed but not in client/server modules.
After the refactoring is done it gets its old name, annoying...

The api project is a required project on the build path of client/server.
I setup and reimported the maven projects several times,
created a new workspace even reinstalled Oxygen.3a, no success.

Is it a new bug in Eclipse Oxygen.3a?

I reimported the project into an older eclipse version (Mars) and there the renaming is executed as expected.

Comment: Have you imported the whole multi module into Eclipse starting from the root of your project?

Comment: yes, absolutly.

Comment: Also I retried it with a another new multi module project, same behaviour, totally reproducible.

Comment: I'm using for a long time in different Eclipse versions works without any issue...Have cleared the `.settings`, `.project`, `.classpath` files before reimporting it?

Comment: you made my day, after deleting these files the refactoring is working! I compared the new with old created eclipse files, there are some differences, especially there was a project name from a totally different module. Copy & Paste i think...